# Dynamic infinite scroller

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create an infinite scroller which can have x amount of items in it hence, dynamic.
The items can have various width and height as shown in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujgdphm0/21/).

The undesired result block illustrates my issue. Should six or less items be entered dynamically, you can literally see a huge green gap on the right with a snap like effect. That is, the items_container is moving out of the viewport.

With the desired result, the transition is smooth and there is no snap like effect. However, how do i know how much item i need to duplicate

**Without resulting in the use of a plugin**, how can I achieve the desired result with CSS and no markup duplication? I wasn't able to find any solution like that. If, i need to duplicate with JQuery how do i ensure the smooth transition.

The issue shows clearly when you run snippet and click full page

```css
.items {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lime;
  height: 230px;
}

.items__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: bannermove 10s linear infinite;
}

.items__el {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

.items__el.small,
.items__el.small::before {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background: red;
}

.items__el.medium,
.items__el.medium::before {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: yellow;
}

.items__el.large,
.items__el.large::before {
  width: 222px;
  height: 222px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Undesired result begin -->
<div class="items">
  <div class="items__container">
    <span class="items__el small"></span>
    <span class="items__el medium"></span>
    <span class="items__el large"></span>
    <span class="items__el small"></span>
    <span class="items__el medium"></span>
    <span class="items__el large"></span>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Undesired result end -->

<!-- desired result begin -->
<div class="items">
  <div class="items__container">
    <span class="items__el small"></span>
    <span class="items__el medium"></span>
    <span class="items__el large"></span>
    <span class="items__el small"></span>
    <span class="items__el medium"></span>
    <span class="items__el large"></span>

    <span class="items__el small"></span>
    <span class="items__el medium"></span>
    <span class="items__el large"></span>
    <span class="items__el small"></span>
    <span class="items__el medium"></span>
    <span class="items__el large"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- desired result end -->
```

Comment: Make your code runnable on stackoverflow.

Comment: The code is now runnable on stackoverflow. cheers